# Two NICs docker host, fixed container source IP, no connection to second subnet

Tags: networking, iptables, docker

We have the following scenario, a docker host with two NICs in two subnets, `ens8: IP 192.168.100.74/24` and `ens9: IP 172.20.102.24/25`, the default bridge `docker0 IP 172.17.0.1/16` and a second bridge `app_net IP 172.21.0.1/24`. `192.168.100.1` is the default gateway on host (internet gateway).

The docker container have a fixed outgoing IP using SNAT, see [Four ways to connect a docker container to a local network - Using NAT](http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/). This is done by two commands, assign target address to host interface `ip addr add 192.168.100.234/24 dev ens8` and add iptables rule `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 172.21.0.4 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.100.234`. Containers are created using IPs from bridge app_net.

On the host I can either ping/traceroute IPs in subnet `192.168.100.x` and in `172.20.102.x` and internet e.g. google.com. Within a container, I can ping/traceroute IPs in subnet `192.168.100.x`, I can also ping e.g. google.com, but I cannot ping anything in `172.20.102.x`, except `172.20.102.24`. See the following output.

```
    # traceroute -I 192.168.100.10
    traceroute to 192.168.100.10 (192.168.100.10), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
    1  172.21.0.1 (172.21.0.1)  0.004 ms  0.003 ms  0.002 ms
    2  192.168.100.10 (192.168.100.10)  0.180 ms  0.158 ms  0.028 ms

    # traceroute -I google.com
    traceroute to google.com (216.58.214.46), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
    1  172.21.0.1 (172.21.0.1)  0.004 ms  0.013 ms  0.002 ms
    2  fritz.box (192.168.100.1)  2.144 ms  3.114 ms  2.697 ms
    3  server.provider.net (xx.yy.250.5)  6.947 ms  7.042 ms  4.305 ms
    4  etc...

    # traceroute -I 172.20.102.24
    traceroute to 172.20.102.24 (172.20.102.24), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
    1  172.20.102.24 (172.20.102.24)  0.004 ms  0.003 ms  0.002 ms

    # traceroute -I 172.20.102.9
    traceroute to 172.20.102.9 (172.20.102.9), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
    1  172.21.0.1 (172.21.0.1)  0.004 ms  0.003 ms  0.002 ms
    2  *  *  *
    3  *  *  * (etc. no response)
```

If I do not add the iptables SNAT rule, containers can ping/traceroute everything, also machines on subnet `172.20.102.x`.

I found an article about multiple NICs and docker(#) with a [stripped down solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/696747/routing-from-docker-containers-using-a-different-physical-network-interface-and/743314#743314) on serverFault, but neither this, nor a deep look into advanced docker networking(#) gave me a clue, why I cannot reach other machines in the ens9 subnet, except the network card itself from within a docker container.

Am I missing something, or is this network scenario just wrong?

(#) Not allowed to post more than two links because of reputation, but the serverFault link together with Google "Docker over multiple network interfaces" should help to find the links.